# error after deleting app from django project

Tags: python, django, modulenotfounderror

I am new to Django so please excuse my ignorance...

I have been working on an e-commerce project with django in VS code. Everything was working fine until I thought I'd add an account feature. From the terminal I did a startapp account. Not long after doing this, I decided to go another route and not make an account app. So I deleted the account directory from the explorer from right clicking and selecting the delete option. Now, when I ran the server to  make sure I didn't break anything, I did in fact break everything. I am using the venv and I do have my Onedrive open since the directory is saved in there. This is the error I got:

```
(Django_projects) PS C:\Users\kylec\OneDrive\Documents\school_files\team_project\Django\bookify> py manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kylec\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner      
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\kylec\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in 
create
    import_module(entry)
  File "c:\users\kylec\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kylec\OneDrive\Documents\school_files\team_project\Django\bookify\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\OneDrive\Documents\school_files\team_project\Django\bookify\manage.py", line 18, in main     
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 111, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 680, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 661, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 344, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 350, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 390, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 411, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 304, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 120, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\kylec\.virtualenvs\Django_projects-1wiE7bc9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 160, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "c:\users\kylec\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1407, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "c:\users\kylec\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1221, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
(Django_projects) PS C:\Users\kylec\OneDrive\Documents\school_files\team_project\Django\bookify> 
 *  History restored 

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run        
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kylec\OneDrive\Documents\school_files\team_project\Django\bookify\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\OneDrive\Documents\school_files\team_project\Django\bookify\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 111, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 680, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 661, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 344, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 350, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 390, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 411, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 304, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 120, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 160, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1407, in exists      
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1221, in stat        
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Thinking that since I deleted "account" I need to revert all the migrations I went to the terminal and tried this:
py manage.py migrate account zero

The following is the error that I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kylec\OneDrive\Documents\school_files\team_project\Django\bookify\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\OneDrive\Documents\school_files\team_project\Django\bookify\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'
```

Comment: It's not that you have deleted an account, it's that you have deleted the Python module called "account.py".  Do you know where that is supposed to live?

Comment: it was in my bookify directory at: C:\Users\kylec\OneDrive\Documents\school_files\team_project\Django\bookify

Comment: I purposely deleted account, but now my server will not at all. It was working previously, before I had created account.py. I'm just curious if I didn't delete all dependencies. I took it out of INSTALLED_APPS in settings

Answer (score 0):

I restored the file and then opened every folder (urls, views, etc) and deleted everything in the files. I did py manage.py makemigrations account and then py manage.py squashmigrations account

-everything is up and running again